# Java program that uses methods from a unique class is not running properly

Tags: java, arrays, class, binary-search, fileoutputstream

I created a BinarySearch class that has three different implementations of binary search. I also created a binary test program that tests the different implementations and writes the results into an output file.  The trouble that I'm having is that the program will randomly pause while running the "runSearch" method in my program, and I have to forcefully stop it.

BinarySearch Class:

```java
import java.util.*;

public class BinarySearch {
    private int [] A;
    private int k;
    public BinarySearch(int [] A, int k) {
        this.A = A;
        this.k = k;
    }

    public static int binBasic (int [] A, int K) {
        // Return the  amount of iterations it took to find k in A uses an integer count to keep track of the iterations
        int count = 0;
        int l = -1;
        int r = A.length;
        // l and r are beyond array bounds
        while (l+1 != r) {
            // Stop when l and r meet
            int i = (l+r)/2; // Check middle of remaining subarray
            if (K == A[i]) return count;
            // Found it
            if (K < A[i]) {
                r = i;
                // In left half
                count++;
            }
            if (K > A[i]) {
                l = i;
                // In right half
                count++;
            }
        }
        return -1;
        // Search value not in A
    }

    public static int bin3 (int [] A, int K) {
        // Return the  amount of iterations it took to find k in A uses an integer count to keep track of the iterations
        int count = 0;
        int l = -1;
        int r = A.length;
        // l and r are beyond array bounds
        while (l+1 != r) {
            // Stop when l and r meet
            int i = l + ((r-l)/3);
            if (K == A[i]) return count;
            // Found it
            if (K < A[i]) {
                r = i;
                // In left half
                count++;
            }
            if (K > A[i]){
                l = i;
                // In right half
                count++;
            }
        }
        return -1;
        // Search value not in A
    }

    public static int binMin2 (int [] A, int K) {
        // Return the  amount of iterations it took to find k in A uses an integer count to keep track of the iterations
        int count=0;
        int l = -1;
        int r = A.length;
        // l and r are beyond array bounds
        while (l+1 != r) {
            // Stop when l and r meet
            int i = r-2;
            if (K == A[i]) return count;
            // Found it
            if (K < A[i]) {
                r = i;
                // In left half
                count++;
            }
            if (K > A[i]) {
                l = i;
                // In right half
                count++;
            }
        }
        return -1;
        // Search value not in A
    }

}
```

Binary Test method:

```java
//runs the three iterations of binarysearch and writes the results into BinarySearchResults.txt
public static void runSearch(int [] A, int k)throws FileNotFoundException {
    BinarySearch x = new BinarySearch(A,k);
    out1.println("The amount of iterations it took to find k in binBasic was: " + x.binBasic(A,k));
    out1.println("The amount of iterations it took to find k in bin3 was: " + x.bin3(A,k));
    out1.println("The amount of iterations it took to fins k in binMin was: " + x.binMin2(A,k));
    out1.println();
}
```

Comment: What is the Q? :-)

Comment: If there are "pauses" that require one to kill the program, the most likely culprit is an infinite loop. Time to break out the debugger!

Comment: Or, generate a thread dump on the program.  The stack should show you where the program is looping.  (There are lots of guides to generating a thread dump, which depends on your platform and possibly on the java vendor.)

Comment: @MS90 The program will either run, or will pause while being run at random.My question is what’s causing this to happen.

Comment: What values are you using for A and k? For A = {1, 2, 3} and k = 1 I get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in binMin2. I can try and debug this tomorrow if nobody has replied until then. A little more info would be helpful though.

Comment: @c_student I’m using randomly generated values and add them to A. Then select k randomly and run the algorithm. Im getting the random numbers from the random class.